# JASidePanelController iOS7 showing contents below status bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Anyone know a fix for this?

There is a discussion going on here as well: https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/pull/164

Comment: yes: add +20 to the origin and remove -20px from the height. works for us :)

Comment: what happens when you present a view controller modally?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is too old but for those users who still have the same problem check my answer here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21426077/1572408

Hope it helps :)