# iOS JASidePanel status bar customization

Tags: ios, ios7, uistatusbar, jasidepanels

I am using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) in my app and everything is so far so good. My design team have come up with a UI design like this, when the side panel is shown or revealed,

[image]

But I am able to reproduce like! this.

[image]

**What all I have tried so far:**

I tried setting the center panels background color to  the image that I have in the right panel - No luck.

I tried setting the sidePanel.view.backgroundColor and also tintColor  - No luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is JASidePanels's bug , however they fixed the issue by doing this: 
in the JASidePanelsController add below code to `_adjustCenterFrame`

```
- (CGRect)_adjustCenterFrame {
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;

    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden) {
                        frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
                        frame.size.height = frame.size.height - 20;
                    }

        } 
...
}
```

Also in `_layoutSideContainers` add :

```
- (void)_layoutSideContainers:(BOOL)animate duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    CGRect leftFrame = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect rightFrame = self.view.bounds;



    if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        if (![UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden) {
                    leftFrame.origin.y = leftFrame.origin.y + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
                    rightFrame.origin.y = rightFrame.origin.y + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
            leftFrame.size.height = leftFrame.size.height - 20;
            rightFrame.size.height = rightFrame.size.height - 20;
                        }
            }

    ...
}
```

reference :

https://github.com/hamin/JASidePanels/commit/81ae7514d275d9242ad268ab818441c8d786a63e

and

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels/pull/164

Answer (score 1):

I tried a simple test base on JASidePanels' demo source code. And got this effect:

[image: screenshot]

If this is not what you want, please ignore this answer and delete it.

---

It works by modifying the source code of JASidePanels:

For testing, I add 
`self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]`

In your situation, you may add `[self.window addSubview:backgroundImageView]`
or `jaSidePanelController.view addSubview:backgroundImageView` (please test this by yourself)

Then resize the left panel's frame by add additional space to let left panel don't cover your background image view for the status bar. In `JASidePanelController#_layoutSidePanels`

PS: for more details, you should read articles about iOS 7 status bar like http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/

BTW: I'm curious that there's no `cornerRadius` in your screenshot.

Comment: I set the corner to 0 as the corner radius is not really Flat UI to me. for doing that look for this in JASlidePanelController: - (void)stylePanel:(UIView *)panel {
    panel.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0f;//here
    panel.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

Just set the cornerRadius 0.0f in JASlidePanelController.m file:

```
- (void)stylePanel:(UIView *)panel {
      //do changes in below cornerRadius
      panel.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0f;
      panel.clipsToBounds = YES;   }
```